# CURL Returning Strange Characters

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to grab the source code of a website so I can parse out football fixtures, my code is:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/scores-fixtures/2019-03-06";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
    'Proxy-Connection: Close',
    'Cookie: PREF=ID=2bb051bfbf00e95b:U=c0bb6046a0ce0334:',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'Connection: Close'
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 


echo substr($output, 0, 12);

?>
```

Output of the substring shown is:

> ���

I need the output in standard text, is that compressed or something?

How do I fix this please?

Thanks.

Comment: try downloading the file to your computer using a browser, or wget, or curl, then open it in e.g. notepad ++ and check if the file is UTF-8 with BOM, if so, those characters are the BOM (Byte order mark), which can essenially be ignored.

Comment: If I open in Notepad it looks fine, standard characters.  They use this:  <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-GB" class="b-pw-1280 b-reith-sans-font"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/>

Comment: windows notepad is not sufficient. Notepad++ or such will tell you what file type it is... and enabling "show all characters" will show non-printable characters

Comment: Thanks, looks fine in Notepad++ too, if I show all characters just adds the CR and LF.

Comment: I just ran your code and saw that it is gzipped. read @bobbyjack s answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need the output in standard text, is that compressed or something?

Yes, exactly that: it's gzip-compressed. Your options are
 **a)** decompress it using e.g. [gzdecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) 
**b)** tell the server you don't want a gzip-encoded response; the easiest way is to let curl handle this for you:

1. delete  `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',` from your header array
2. Add: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');` somewhere before you `curl_exec()`

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting standard text back but not the source code I was expecting.  See my question for the output.

Comment: Ah it's there, just very well hidden!  Thanks!

Comment: Option 3: ask curl to decompress it automatically with `CURLOPT_ENCODING`